# Azure Devops install and run the Databrick CLI

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

The [databricks-cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/cli/) is a Python module to communicate with the Databricks API and would easily be installed with pip in an Azure Devops pipeline:

```yaml
- stage: Test
  jobs:
    - job: InstallRequirements
      steps:
       - script: |
           python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
           pip install databricks-cli
       - script: databricks --version
```

But this gives an unexpected error with the second script:

> /_w/_temp/eeb8461a-d19b-4013-973b-0c1787ab17a3.sh: line 1: databricks: command not found

I have also tried to flag the command as a Python module e.g. run databricks as `python -m databricks --version`

Comment: Hi ,glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning after installation included a hint:

```
WARNING: The script tabulate is installed in '/home/AzDevops_azpcontainer/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
```

Which can be resolved by [prepend](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) to PATH after pip install:

```yaml
- script: |
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
    pip install databricks-cli
    echo '##vso[task.prependpath]/home/AzDevops_azpcontainer/.local/bin'
```

(Syntax beauty is hard to find but at least it works)